# How do you make a django field reference to a python class?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, github3.py

I am working on a project to expand a testing suite that my company uses. One of this things that was asked of me was to link the website to our Github source for code so that the dev team could continue tracking the issues there instead of trying to look in two places. I was able to do this but the problem is that every time the a bug is reported an issue is opened.

I want to add a field to my Django model that tracks an [Issue object](http://github3py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/issues.html#issue-objects/) (from the github3.py wrapper) that is sent to Github. I want to use this to check if an Issue has already been created in Github by that instance of the BugReport and if it has been created, edit the Issue instead of creating another issue in Github that is a duplicate. Does Django have a something that can handle this sort of reference?

I am using Django 1.3.1 and Python 2.7.1

**EDIT**

I was able to figure my specific problem out using esauro's suggestions. However, as  mkoistinen said, If this problem came up in a program where the work-around was not as easy as this one was, *should* an object reference be created like I had originally asked about or is that bad practice? and if it is okay to make an object reference like that, how would you do it with the Django models?

Comment: Each issue has a number, hasn't it?, you could link that number instead of object.

Comment: True, But I wanted to have the issue itself referenced so that I could call the edit function without having to loop through all of the issues in a repository looking for that number, which could end up being slow as the issue number grows.

Comment: Interesting question. I think its debatable whether you _should_ do this, but I will be watching to see if there is a practical approach regardless.

Comment: I never worked with github3.py wrapper, but, as it is a wrapper, you could use the equivalent to [this](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#get-a-single-issue), to get the single issue, instead of looping.

Comment: @esauro That is a good point, I had forgotten about that method as I did not think that I had any access to the issue number.

Comment: Creating an object reference seems weird to me. What are you gonna do if you need to reboot the process?, what about multiprocess environments?. The object reference won't work, so, IMHO, it's not a good idea to create objects reference from Django models to regular python objects. If I really need something like that, i'd probably use a model class as a wrapper using signals or maybe overwriting save method to do whatever I need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the creator of github3.py.

If you want to get the issue itself via a number, there are a couple different ways to do this. I'm not sure how you're interacting with the API but you can do:

```
import github3


i = githbu3.issue('repo_owner', 'repo_name', issue_number)
```

or

```
import github3


r = github3.repository('repo_owner', 'repo_name')
i = r.issue(issue_number)
```

or

```
import github3


g = github3.login(client_key='client_key', client_secret='client_secret')
i = g.issue('repo_owner', 'repo_name', issue_number)
# or
r = g.repository('repo_owner', 'repo_name')
i = r.issue(issue_number)
```

otherwise if you're looking for something that's in an issue without knowing the number:

```
import github3


r = github3.repository('repo_owner', 'repo_name')
for i in r.iter_issues():
    if 'text to search for' in i.body_text:
        i.edit('...')
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I was able to find a way of storing the issue number as I created the issue, then hitting the api using the 2nd recommendation you had with that issue's number to edit/comment the issue once its created.

Comment: Ah ok. If you're searching through issues on the API, you can also use [this](http://github3py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/github.html#github3.github.GitHub.search_issues) It will return a different [issue object](http://github3py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/legacy.html#github3.legacy.LegacyIssue) but you should be able to use that to get the issue number.